# ¿Consulta con Eloquent para traer solo cierto campo de todos mis registros?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola lo que intento es traer todos los registros de mi tabla pero el campo que quiero traer solo es "table_name", he hecho la siguiente consulta utilizando Eloquent, mi pregunta realmente sería cual es la mejor manera ya que he leido que algunas consultas pueden se más optimizadas que otras ¿Y como puedo saber esto?
Esta es mi consulta con Eloquent:

```
CatAdministrator::all()->pluck('table_name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si al método `all()` no le específicas las columnas de las cuales quieres recuperar los valores entonces hará una selección general.

Entonces puedes redactarla así:

```
CatAdministrador::all(['table_name']);
```

Cuya salida producida sería algo así:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    .....
]
```

Sin embargo si empleas a `pluck()` de esta forma:

```
CatAdministrator::pluck('table_name');
```

La salida producida sería:

```
[valor1, valor2, ......, valorN]
```

Comentarios finales:

- Si dejas la consulta actual entonces primero deberá obtener una *collection* con toda la información y posterior generar un *array* con los valores que filtras mediante `pluck` lo cual no luce práctico.
- Recomiendo repases ambos métodos ya te ayudan a obtener la información necesaria (*haciendo las ediciones correspondientes*), la cuestión es en que formato te resulte mas funcional